# IOS, UICollectionview

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

New to IOS and objective C and been doing several tutorials, with adding buttons, textfields etc. Been looking alot on stackoverflow, which has been very helpful :) Now I am trying to create a collectionview within a frame and then put a button below it. I can get a button to show up, and the top half of the screen where I have defined the collection to appear turns black, while the rest goes white, as intended. Currently the collection should come up with a label telling me the cell number, so very basic. Not sure if I'm setting up my views wrong, or if there is something wrong with my CellViews.
I have created a mainView controller, where I have defined my button and collection view, like this:
MainViewController.h:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout>

@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UICollectionView *collectionView;
@property(nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIButton *diaryButton;

- (id)init;
```

My .m looks like this:

```
@implementation MainViewController
@synthesize collectionView;
@synthesize diaryButton;

- (id) init {

self = [super init];
if (self) {

    CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake(10, 250, 70, 30);
    diaryButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [diaryButton setFrame:buttonFrame];
    [diaryButton setTitle:@"Diary" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];
    layout.itemSize = CGSizeMake(64.0, 64.0);
    layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 4;
    layout.minimumLineSpacing = 4;
    layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredVertically;
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(2.0, 2.0, 2.0, 2.0);
    CGRect collectionFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 200);
    collectionView = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:collectionFrame collectionViewLayout:layout];


    [self.view addSubview:collectionView];
    [self.view addSubview:diaryButton];
    //[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
}
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
     [self.collectionView registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID"];
}


- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 30;
}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"ID" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", indexPath.row];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label];
    return cell;
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// collection view delegate methods ////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"cell #%d was selected", indexPath.row);
}
```

My appdelegate looks like this:

```
   @synthesize mainVC;

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    self.mainVC = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
    [self.window addSubview:mainVC.view];
    //self.window.rootViewController = mainVC;
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking, or what's wrong with the results you're getting. Could you be more explicit about what you're trying to find out and what you've done to diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why your collection isn't showing anything, but you're missing the numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: method from the UICollectionViewDataSource.  The collection view might be assuming that the number of sections is 0.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewDataSource_protocol/Reference/Reference.html

Also, did you set the datasource and delegate to self for your UICollectionView?

Comment: numberOfSectionsInCollectionView: method seems to default to 1, but I have it defined now anyway.
How do I set the datasource?  Am I telling the UICollectionView what its datasource is? (which is the mainController, I guess). Did not find any methods where I could set the datasource. Am I misunderstanding you?

Comment: found the setDatasource method. Not sure how I missed it the first time, and it works :)
Thanks alot!

Comment: Nice, glad it helped.  If you don't want to set it in code, you can set the delegate and datasource through Interface Builder by holding down control, then click and drag the mouse from the UICollectionView to the MainViewController and release.  Then check datasource.  The same goes for the delegate.  If the answer helped, don't forget to mark it as the answer :-)